# TextFields delegate not working in Detail View Controller of a SplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, delegates, uitextfield

I'm using these methods to make the view "animate" in order to prevent the keyboard to cover a text field, and it works perfectly both on iPhone and in a normal iPad View Controller ..but if i use them in a Detail View Controller of a Split View Controller it does not work.
p.s. yes i Ctrl-dragged the delegate to the view

```
CGFloat animatedDistance;
static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //move view when begin editing a TextField (avoid keyboard to hide it)
    CGRect textFieldRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect =
    [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator =
    midline - viewRect.origin.y
    - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator =
    (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION)
    * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
        viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;
    }
    else
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
        viewFrame.origin.x += animatedDistance;
    }

    //CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    //viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //when keyboard is dismissed return to the original view
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;
    }
    else {
        viewFrame.origin.x -= animatedDistance;
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Any idea why does not work?

Comment: Can you add breakpoints in either or both of the methods above and see if they are being hit when the keyboard shows or hides?

Comment: yes they are, the Logs i put inside are shown